# How to deal with an bad project manager?

Tags: communication, colleagues, project-management

I am in charge of producing web applications, internal software, and other apps at MEGACOMPANY.  I have pretty good say on these projects and can work on what I want within reason but at the same time if people want something I try to help out and stay on their timeline.

We have a new project manager as of a few months ago.  This person is basically in charge of getting all of the requirements for my projects and well anything related to them as well as other tasks that sometimes fall into the technical realm and sometimes don't.

I get along well with the project manager but I feel that this person is really started to adversely effect my reputation and more importantly my work.

Issue examples:

- PM often has an agenda for the applications I am developing.  If someone differs from their opinion they do not seek that person's input.  I am very well connected to our entire group and they are used to having a basically seamless upgrade cycle.  So when the PM talks with me I am really confused that we are discussing A-F when several upper level managers have expressed clearly they would like G-X too.  When I mention G-X the PM seems annoyed that I have already talked to the stakeholders and then says that they should be talking to them.
- The PM actually asked for project management software as well as most of the managers in our large group.  I have completed the software and it is great.  The PM keeps delaying the launch by acting like they do not have the time, that they need extra fields added that were never in scope, or just simply blows off simple requests.

I can give 10 other examples from the past 4 months.  The PM is assigned to our group to make projects run more smoothly.  The exact opposite is happening.  People seem to be going out of their way to schedule meetings that the PM can't attend.  Yet the PM makes sure that nothing goes forward unless it meets their needs and approval.

Both the PM and I report to a high level executive and I guess we are more or less on the same level.  The person we are reporting to is in the PMs location half way around the world from me.  If I had a relationship with the executive I would bring these things up right away.  But I don't, the PM has his ear, and I feel that anything that I bring up may damage relationships long-term.  I have had several calls with the PM (which the PM cancels half at the last minute).  What is the next step?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20954/discussion-on-question-by-blankip-how-to-deal-with-an-bad-project-manager).

Answer (score 3):

OK, after a long back-and forth in comments sure to get deleted, here's what I feel would be a viable course of action:

1. Communicate to your VP that the PM is not helping you, but rather is becoming a roadblock with communicating with the user base.
2. Also let the VP know that you really do appreciate the efforts, but since your primary user base is internal, and mainly managers, there really is not a need for the PM to "Manage the managers" for you.
3. Let him know that your former colleague was very helpful, and that you would really appreciate someone filling that (business analyst?) role, again.

Then, be prepared for the fireworks.  The VP will either have an epiphany, and get you back to where things were working well, or ask the PM why you're so unhappy, and the PM will be upset with you and throw you under the bus.

I was hoping for the first outcome, but got the second.

I hope your outcome is better.

Comment: I have never saw that skipping official path worked. @blankip if you are right - you have two choices - work on, he will take credits, or go on war. At least be prepared, look around if there is better offer? Why to stick with old one? Most people quiting job mentions direct boss as reason.

Answer (score 0):

Put simply, the PM is trying to establish their value by both pigeon holing you and making sure they are THE person in charge.  You can be sure that they are likely even trying to convince the VP that you should be directly reporting to them.  After all, wouldn't it be easier on the VP if they didn't have to deal with those *developers*?...

This is naturally leading to confusion on your part.

There really are only three options.  The first is to do as Wesley said and talk to the VP directly.  The problem here is that it's going to boil down to how good your credentials are versus how tied in the PM is to the VP.  If the PM is a friend of the VPs then, well, it won't end well for you.  It would help if you knew *exactly* why this person was hired in the first place.

Regardless, I suspect politics is already not in your favor so this will be a tough issue.  If the VP even thinks that managing you in too much of a burden then this will not go your way at all.

The second option is to accept your new overlord.  This may have some consequences in your career path at this company.  That said, if the PM is tight with the VP then this may be your only option for a future at this company.

Third option is to exit stage left.

Me, I'd do some recon and figure out what the relationship is between the PM and VP.  Hopefully you've helped the VP's secretary with something...  If there isn't one then I'd do what Wesley suggested asap.  If there is, then I'd decide how much I want to continue working there.